# Is there any practical point overriding hashcode if the class is not used as a key in a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, hashcode

I have recently been learning about the hashCode function and HashMaps, and have experimented with creating my own hashCode function for my own classes. From the research I have done, the only reason, from a practical point of view, that hashCode needs to be overridden seems to be if the class is going to be used as a key in a HashMap, or if the hashCode function is used elsewhere. I understand it's part of the equals and hashCode contracts to override, and in the future another user may want to use it in a HashMap, but I want to know for understanding's sake, if the class were **never** used as a key, would I still need to override the hashCode function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you override `equals`, you should always also override `hashCode`, even if you don't expect your object to be stored in a `HashMap` or `HashSet`. There are several reasons.

1. Your objects might not be stored in a `HashMap` or `HashSet` **today**, but six months from now, you might decide to do so, and things will seem to work ok until they break horribly. At that point, you'll say to yourself "%$^^&%*& I should have implemented `hashCode`!"
2. Your objects might be used by somebody else, and **they** expect you to implement `hashCode`. When **they** store your objects in a `HashMap` and it doesn't work, they'll say "that %$^^&%*& Aaron should have implemented `hashCode`!"
3. You might hand your object off to some library, and unbeknownst to you, that library might want to store your object in a hash-based collection.
4. If your object is ever stored inside a container object, even if that container isn't itself hash-based, the **container's** `hashCode` is often logically dependent upon your object's `hashCode`. For example, see [`Arrays.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#hashCode--) or [`Optional.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#hashCode--).
5. The `hashCode` is sometimes used for short-circuiting an equality check.

The bottom line is that the point of the `hashCode`/`equals` contract is that everybody relies on the contract to be implemented properly. Assumptions about adherence to the contract are laced throughout large systems, not just in hash-based collections.

Comment: Is #5 true outside of hash-based collections?

Comment: @shmosel I think I've seen this done before (outside of a hash-based collection) but I might have do a lot of digging to find an example. But it's legal according to the equals/hashCode contract, so I think it's likely that somebody somewhere has done it.

Comment: @shmosel Ah, didn't take long at all. See this [equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.aic-expresso/aic-expresso/1.1.0/com/sri/ai/expresso/core/DefaultCompoundSyntaxTree.java#154) method. I don't know much about what this code does, but it looks correct. It caches hashCode values, and avoids an expensive equality check if hashCodes are unequal.

Comment: That's a class checking *its own* hash code, so it doesn't directly parallel OP's case, where `equals()` is obviously not relying on `hashCode()`. I understand that it's possible to do similar short-circuiting externally; I was just wondering if it happens in the real world.

Comment: @shmosel In that example, the hashCode being computed is based on the hashCodes of subtrees. I don't know if it's actually recursive, but it looks like it. If it's possible for a user object to be plugged into a tree node somewhere, this would be an example of #4: the hashCode of the tree might depend on the hashCodes of data in the tree nodes. Given that equality comparison can be quite expensive, it looks like this example caches the hashCodes and uses #5 for short-circuiting.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply, this and all the other answers have been helpful! I feel as though I should have rephrased my question however, since I do understand why it should be used and that in the future there may be cases where hashCode would be required. I guess I really just wanted to know: if I'm simply creating a class for myself which will only be used by myself, will the hashCode function ever be called by anything other than a hash collection? And is it only ever called if the class is used as the key (apart from short circuiting a equality check like you said)?

Comment: In my hypothetical, the class is also never put in a collection that may itself be put in a hash-based collection @stuart marks

Comment: @AaronBarnard The main uses of hashCode are 1) by hash-based collections; 2) by containers that aren't necessarily hash-based, but which use it in computation of their own hashCodes; and 3) short-circuiting of equals and similar cases. This last case is quite uncommon compared to the first two. If you're sure your object is and will never be used in any of these cases, you can skip implementing hashCode. It's not like the JVM magically calls hashCode or anything, and failing to override it would cause this magic to break.

Answer (score 4):

You should always implement `hashCode` whenever you implement `equals`, because even if *you* never put your objects in a HashMap, you have no idea what the libraries you're using might do. Libraries are free to rely on your objects' `hashCode` without telling you.

Even if you just have your IDE autogenerate `hashCode` along with `equals`, or even if it's just

```
public int hashCode() {
    raise RuntimeException("This type doesn't support hashCode (for now).");
}
```

you should never leave your `hashCode` inconsistent with your `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

No. But remember that key in `HashMap` is the same as a value in `HashSet`, so you're also making it impossible to store that object in a `HashSet` (at least if you intend to use it for content equality).

Comment: That's actually not quite true. See my answer. Or you should perhaps elaborate on what you mean by "content equality"

Comment: Yes it is. If you only need reference equality, then it's not a problem, but if you want content equality, then it is. Look up content equality vs. reference equality if it's a new term for you.

Comment: Given that the OP seem to be pretty new to Java, I think an answer should be more precise.

Comment: He seems to understand the equals/hashCode contract. You're just repeating things he already knows in your answer. I on the other hand gave him an answer to his question, i.e. "no".

Comment: Isn't the term usually "value equality"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct if you are not using your object in key or any other hash based data structure you don't need to override the hashcode method of Object.JVM provide a default implementation of hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be the default implementation of `hashCode` that uses the identity hash code internally. That is the class can be used in a `HashSet` or even as key in a `HashMap`, but this will not be very efficient or meaningful - there is no point in using a `Set` without implementing `equals`.

One important thing to consider is the contract between `equals` and `hashCode`. That is, if you override `equals` you have to override `hashCode` in a way that it returns the same value for two instances that are equal wrt. your implementation of `equals`. In other words the following rule must always hold:

If `a.equals(b) == true` then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`